# Is it possible to restore databse from cpanel without backup?

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, database-restore

Unfortunately i have dropped all table from a database of a WordPress website, but i have not any backup. Is it possible to restore all table from cpanel without backup?
Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to say that without a backup file there is nothing you can do. Did you try contacting your hosting company to see if they happen to have a backup? Sometimes they do.

I wish you luck.